# Multibyte string error when writing in MySQL from R with RMySQL dbWriteTable

Tags: mysql, r

Each time I try to use the dbWriteTable function from RMySQL package in R 3.0 (but also in R 2.15 before) I get this error `"Erreur dans tolower(avail) : chaîne de charactères multioctets incorrecte 45",` which means something like `"Error in tolower(avail) : Multibyte string error X".`  And I can't find any solution, I don't even understand where this error is generated.

Here are the facts : I work on Mac OS X 10.9.1 but had this error on 10.8.x and I have it as well on Debian.  Both MySQL and R are on the same machine (or not, it doesn't make any difference).  For testing purpose I have created at table with only numerical values and I read it's content with RMySQL (no problem) then try to reinject it in MySQL with dbWriteTable, and boom.  Here's the R script :

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
library(DBI)
library(RMySQL)

conn <- dbConnect("MySQL", user="userr", password="passworrd", dbname="dbtest")

res <- dbSendQuery(conn, statement = paste("SELECT * FROM testable"))
input <- fetch(res, n = -1)

dbWriteTable(conn, "testable2", input, row.names = T, overwrite = FALSE, append = T)  

dbDisconnect(conn)
```

The table content being :

```
  id testval
1  1   76
2  2   47417
```

The user owns the DB. The fetch works fine but not the dbWriteTable.  The error is probably related to some character coding but I can't figure out what.

I'm using R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25), RMySQL 0.9-3, DBI 0.2-7 and MySQL 5.6.14, Mac OS X 10.9.1 .
I have the same issue on Rstudio server hosted on a Debian machine.

The Mysql on Debian (don't know where to find these on Mac) log says :

```
- 140211 14:04:15      24 Connect   userr@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx on dbtest
- 140211 14:04:32      24 Query show tables
- 140211 14:04:52      24 Quit
```

So, my humble wish is that someone could put me on the good track !

Didier

Answer (score 1):

Solution : it was a collation problem in the database; I created another DB with Coding UTF-8 (like the first one) but this time with collation utf8_general_ci instead of utf8_bin, and there it worked perfectly. Long question, short answer.